# create variable as a function of another variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Okay. Basically, I want to define a complex variable within a SQL statement and then define another variable as a "function" of the first. I've searched around and can find no indication of how I might accomplish this. I can always just copypaste the code, but that makes it SO messy! See my (erroneous) example below. **true file** is the first variable and **location** is the second.

```
select
    true_file = RIGHT(url.FULL_PATH, CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(url.FULL_PATH)) - 1),
    location = RIGHT(url.FULL_PATH, LEN(url.FULL_PATH) - LEN(true_file) - 9)
from files f
join BBLEARN_cms_doc.dbo.XYF_URLS url
    on url.FILE_ID = substring(f.file_name, 6, len(f.file_name) - 7)
where f.file_name like '/xid-%'
order by url.FULL_PATH;
```

But obviously, we get an "invalid column name" error when trying to run any functions on true_file. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use a derived table or CTE so that you only have to derive the expression once.

Comment: You can calculate true_file in a cross apply and then use the calculated value in the column list.